# using WebClient UploadFile Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, webclient

When I write to a file and upload the same file to FTP site, I get `Thread was being aborted` error.

```
 FileIoUtility.WriteDataToFile(skillsSummaryData, SkillSummaryFileLocation);

                if (!IsFileLocked(SkillSummaryFileLocation))
                {
                    using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUsername, FtpPassword);
                        var uri = new Uri($"{FtpHost}SkillSummary.txt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                        byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(uri, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile,
                            SkillSummaryFileLocation);
                        var response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
                    }
                }
```

Here is my WriteDataToFile method:

```
public static void WriteDataToFile(string data, string fileLocation, bool append = false)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileLocation))
            {
                File.Create(fileLocation).Dispose();
            }

            lock (Locker)
            {
                using (FileStream file =
                    new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        writer.Write(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If I skip the following line and run the upload then it works.

```
FileIoUtility.WriteDataToFile(skillsSummaryData, SkillSummaryFileLocation);
```

Exception doesn't give anything more than **Thread was being aborted**. How can I make this work?

Comment: You probably having a credential issue trying to use a username and password.  I would try to use default credentials which your window login credentials.

Comment: @jdweng not sure how could it be related to credentials, but I tried it myWebClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; no use.